# Way to create a list in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am wondering about the difference between these two options to create a list of string. Which one to use when creating a list in Java?

**Option 1**

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Option 2**

```
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: the `List` is an interface of which implemented by `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc. you should check the javadocs for more info. and a bit understanding in OOP for which one you should use (esp. inheritance stuff).

Comment: The answer is "it depends".

Comment: Option 1 is the commonly used way, but it depends on the task.

Comment: Always read *The Java Tutorials* before posting a question on the basics of Java. Oracle Corp publishes those online free-of-cost. You would have found: [*The `List` interface*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html). The second sentence answers your question.